# Issue with Application.DoEvents()

Tags: vb.net

I have used `Application.DoEvents()` in my code so that I can exit a loop with a button press, I am having an issue where I have to click on the screen before I can press this exit button, thus needing two clicks. This happens every time I play then try to stop the program, without closing it. How would I fix this?

```
Do While StopProgram = False
    Application.DoEvents()
    RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
    Me.Refresh()
    If DirectionPositive = False Then
        Angle += 1
        If Angle = 51 Then
            Angle = 49
            DirectionPositive = True
        End If
    ElseIf DirectionPositive = True Then
        Angle -= 1
        If Angle = -51 Then
            Angle = -49
            DirectionPositive = False
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

---

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    StopProgram = False
    RunningProgram()
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    StopProgram = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Many weirdo things can happen when you use DoEvents().  This one sounds like an issue with the Capture property.  We can't see you doing this wrong.

Comment: Is there any other way I can do the same thing with something else?

Comment: DoEvents is positively discouraged. As alternative, you could use a `BackgroundWroker`, `Thread` or `Task`; but we can't tell what your issue is from the code you posted so I doubt it will fix it.

Comment: Did you come from VB5/6? Things have changed since then - what you _think_ `DoEvents` does now and what it _actually_ does are two different things.

Comment: I have only ever used this language, it is what I learnt in college (Second year now doing a project with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround:  It will work OK if you use MouseDown instead of Click events.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this has fixed it.