# Application.DoEvents() CheckBox Bug (VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I was having problems running my application when (God Mode) was running... I found online, that it seems to be a common bug. The fix is to put `Application.DoEvents()` Within the loop, which I did... But now everytime I turn God Mode on, The CheckBoxes bug out, when they're clicked they activate... The program doesn't stop responding but there needs to be two clicks for the program to visually show that it's active:

[image]

Full Code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
            WriteDMAInteger("Dishonored", GetModuleHandle("Dishonored", "Dishonored.exe") + &H100C810, {&H344}, 70, 1, 4)
        Loop Until CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I dont think vba has a God Mode.  Try DemiGod mode.

Comment: I programmed a game hack that gives god mode in game

Comment: @Plutonix      Very funny... :/

Comment: It's funny when people name their programs. Sounds nerdy (no offense).

Comment: [FIX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179605/7055069)

Comment: @Crush  I haven't named it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Application.DoEvents()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171578/issue-with-application-doevents)

Comment: usually loops and busy wait in event handlers are a bad idea. How often do you need to call `WriteDMAInteger`? You can use a `Timer` instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

Comment: `I found online, that it seems to be a common bug. The fix is to put Application.DoEvents() Within the loop` - Let me make some things clear: **A)** It most certainly _**was not**_ a bug that your UI froze without `Application.DoEvents()`! This happens when you run a constant loop on it as you keep it busy all the time. Use a timer or a [**BackgroundWorker**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the load off of the UI thread instead.

Comment: **B)** For future reference, [`Application.DoEvents()` is _**never**_ the solution to problem A](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/), multithreading or timers is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate, don't use `Application.DoEvents()`  It's more trouble than it's worth.  Instead, use a timer.

Drag a Timer control onto your form from the Toolbox.  Set its `Interval` property to something suitable (like 100 ms).  Add the Tick event and call your `WriteDMAInteger` method in that event.  In your check box's changed event simply enable or disable the timer:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    'Enables the time if the checkbox is checked
    Timer1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WriteDMAInteger("Dishonored", GetModuleHandle("Dishonored", "Dishonored.exe") + &H100C810, {&H344}, 70, 1, 4)
End Sub
```

With the timer's interval set to 100 ms, the `WriteDMAInteger` method will be called 10 times per second.  You can experiment with a smaller value than 100 for the interval, but the limit will be about 50ms.